# Pandas Timegrouper on Dataframe using aggregate function count

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on Timegrouper on Data Frame from Excel and trying to do a Pviot using Date as column header and Time as row and aggregate count on Y is "Barton LLC".

```
Data.xls 
X        Y               Z               D
740150  Barton LLC  B1-20000    2014-01-01 02:21:51
740150  Barton LLC  B1-50809    2014-01-01 02:21:51
740150  Barton LLC  B1-53102    2014-01-01 02:21:51
740150  Barton LLC  S2-16558    2014-01-02 21:21:01
740150  Barton LLC  B1-86481    2014-01-02 21:21:01
740150  Curlis L    S1-06532    2014-01-02 21:21:01
740150  Barton LLC  S1-47412    2014-01-02 21:21:01
740150  Barton LLC  B1-33364    2014-01-02 21:21:01
740150  Barton LLC  S1-93683    2014-02-07 04:34:50
740150  Barton LLC  S2-10342    2014-02-07 04:34:50
```

Tried using resample and pivot and timegrouper but got sequence of errors

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
ndf = df[df['Type'].eq('df')].pivot_table(columns= ['Y'],values='Y',
index=pd.Grouper(key='D',freq='H'),aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)
```

Result

```
         2014-01-01,2014-01-02,2014-02-07
 02:21    3,NaN,NaN              
 21:21    NaN,4,NaN
 04:34    NaN,NaN,2
```

Comment: what's the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the `datetime` column in `date` and `time` and use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['date'] = df['D'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['D'].dt.time
pd.pivot_table(df, 'D', 'time', 'date', aggfunc='count')

date       2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-02-07
time                                        
02:21:51         3.0         NaN         NaN
04:34:50         NaN         NaN         2.0
21:21:01         NaN         5.0         NaN
```

Note that you were missing one count for the date `2014-01-02 21:21:01`

Comment: Tried but it was error..
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):

pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'D'

Comment: adding `df.D = pd.to_datetime(df.D)` in the beginning?

Comment: @ yatu - How to use only HH:MM discarding Secs .

Comment: Change the second line with `df['time'] = df['D'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')`

`

Comment: @ yatu , yes its working can we use cumcount in pivot like this 
pd.pivot_table(df, 'D', 'time', 'date', aggfunc='cumcount')

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert `datetime`s to custom strings:

```
df.D = pd.to_datetime(df.D)

ndf = pd.crosstab(df['D'].dt.strftime('%H:%M').rename('H'), df['D'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) 
print (ndf)
D      2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-02-07
H                                        
02:21           3           0           0
04:34           0           0           2
21:21           0           5           0
```

---

```
ndf = pd.crosstab(df['D'].dt.time.rename('T'), df['D'].dt.date) 
print (ndf)
D         2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-02-07
T                                           
02:21:51           3           0           0
04:34:50           0           0           2
21:21:01           0           5           0
```

Comment: no there is error when tried running ..

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2687         else:
-> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2689 
   2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):


pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

Comment: @J.RAM - What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: print (df.columns)
Index(['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'D'], dtype='object')

Comment: @J.RAM - And `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: it works after adding 
df.D = pd.to_datetime(df.D)
df['date'] = df['D'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['D'].dt.time

Comment: how to use HH:MM alone , ignoring SS